# j2me and ksoap How to get specific element in asp.net webservice

Tags: java, android, asp.net, java-me, ksoap

I am using ksoap with j2me. I am passing the user name and password to asp.net web    service method  and the web service returns  the dataset to me. My problem is how can I 
    get  Get “Display Name” element from this ksoap response (data set)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    - <DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    - <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    - <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    - <xs:complexType>
    - <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    - <xs:element name="Users">
    - <xs:complexType>
    - <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Userid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      <xs:element name="DisplayName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      <xs:element name="Role" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      <xs:element name="SessionId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="UserAccess">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Refno" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="UserId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="MenuId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="Control" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  </DataSet>
```

Comment: if any one can answer this i can use the same pattern for andriod !

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
envelope.implicitTypes = true
```

and navigate the Soap Objects using the SoapObject approach, like this:

```
SoapObject list = (SoapObject)response;

for(int i=0; i < list.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
    SoapObject obj = (SoapObject)list.getProperty(i);
```